# How to implement Nofollow/Noindex in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa, seo

I want to implement NoFollow and NoIndex for every item in Sitecore but I am using SXA. Problem is there is no common template inherited among all of the items. Is there any way I can implement the same functionality using the checkbox field?

Comment: You want to have <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> in your pages?

Comment: @PeterProcházka Yes, if the checkbox "NoIndex" is selected meta value should change like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you could do it:

1. create a base template with the checkbox(es) you want
2. add this base template to all project templates needed
3. create a (custom) rendering that has the meta tag as output based upon the checkboxes (include the necessary checks in case those are not present)
4. add the rendering to the Meta partial design (which probably is already included in all page designs)